# git svn fetch specific directory

Tags: git, svn, version-control, fetch, git-svn

Is it possible to fetch specific directories using git svn? I am trying to fetch multiple directories that match a name "XYZ" in "trunk/Path". "XYZ" is in multiple paths.

```
git svn init --stdlayout --no-minimize-url --trunk=trunk/Path

git svn fetch  --revision 1234:HEAD --authors-file=authors.txt --include-paths="^.*trunk\/subdirpath1/XYZ" 
git svn fetch  --revision 1234:HEAD --authors-file=authors.txt --include-paths="^.*trunk\/subdirpath2/XYZ" 
git svn fetch  --revision 1234:HEAD --authors-file=authors.txt --include-paths="^.*trunk\/subdirpath3/XYZ"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git svn clone of a single directory of SVN repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865386/git-svn-clone-of-a-single-directory-of-svn-repository)

Comment: this post does not show how to fetch multiple directories that matches a name "XYZ" in a repo. "XYZ" can be in different paths in "trunk/Path"

Comment: It is a perl regex, so you can specify a pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can fetch specific directories. Detail steps as below:

#### 1. Add include-paths in `.git/config`.

Open the `.git/config` file add `include-paths = /path/to/specify` under `[svn-remote "svn"]`. So the config file will look like:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
    include-paths = subdirpath1/XYZ|subdirpath2/XYZ|subdirpath3/XYZ
    url = https://url/for/svn/repo
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
```

Note: paths for `include-paths` should contains all the path you want to fetch. Such as if there has the directory `trunk/subdirpath4/XYZ`, you should also add it in `config` file.

#### 2. Fetch related path with `--include-paths` option for `git svn fetch`:

```
git svn fetch --include-paths="subdirpath1/XYZ|subdirpath2/XYZ|subdirpath3/XYZ"
```

Then it will fetch the related svn revisions.

Comment: If I had to update include-paths and ignore-paths, how do I do it. I tried to edit .git/config directly using vim .git/config but git svn fetch does not get the directories I am looking for

Comment: I used only step 1 on this. For the 2 second step, I just did `git svn fetch --authors-file="c:\web\authors.txt"` (I have a authors.txt file containing all the svn authors).